# Get Rank of data from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$data = array(
  'sam' => 40,
  'james' => 40,
  'sunday' => 39,
  'jude' => 45
);
```

I want to rank the names in the array by value and return their rank order as in the array below:

```
$final_data = array(
  'sam' => 2,
  'james' => 2,
  'sunday' => 4,
  'jude' => 1
);
```

Since `jude` has the highest value, they get the value `1`. `sam` and `james` are tied for second, so they both get `2` (`3` is skipped since no one is in third place). `sunday` has the 4th highest score, so they get `4`

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "with respect to their position"?

Comment: Do you mean position by rank?

Comment: How did you go from the first array to the last array?

Comment: @Jerodev That is the question

Comment: OP wants to desc sort the array and set rank by item position in sorted array

Comment: What have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Shouldn't 'sunday' be 3, and not 4?

Comment: Try look into the built-in php function `sort()` and `rsort()`.

Comment: @Martin, when 2 values are the same, the next position is skipped. When 3 values are same, the next two values are skipped and so on.

Comment: @Mehdi , yes, position by rank. 
The first array is a result of many manipulations, and that is what we have now. we want to get the second array from the first so that we can give the students their position based on their score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the array in reverse order and count the position/rank like this:

```
$data = array('sam'=>40, 'james'=>40, 'sunday'=>39, 'jude'=>45);
arsort($data); // sort reverse order
$i = 0;
$prev = "";
$j = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $val){ // loop array
    if($val != $prev){ // if values are the same as previous
        $i++; // add one 
        $i += $j; // add counter of same values
        $j=0; 
    }else{
        $j++; // this is if two values after eachother are the same (sam & james)
    }
    $new[$key] = $i; // create new array with name as key and rank as position
    $prev = $val; // overwrite previous value
}
var_dump($new);
```

output:

```
array(4) {
  ["jude"] => 1
  ["sam"] => 2
  ["james"] => 2
  ["sunday"] => 4
}
```

https://3v4l.org/4YvH9

With three values 40 it returns:

```
array(5) {
  ["jude"] => 1
  ["sam"] => 2
  ["james"] => 2
  ["tom"] => 2
  ["sunday"] => 5
}
```